# Can template infer type of argument of std::function?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement js style async/await. the function below returns a function that returns std::future object.

```
template <typename TResult, typename... TArgs>
std::function<std::future<TResult>(TArgs...)> async(std::function<TResult(TArgs...)> callback) {
    return [=]() {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, callback);
    };
}
```

and I execute the function like below:

```
auto test = asyncTest([=](const std::string &text) mutable {
    static int i = 0;
    await(1000);
    titleText.set(std::to_string(i) + text);
    i++;
});

test("asdf");
```

I got a compile error with this thing:

> error: no matching function for call to 'async'

and

> note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against '(lambda)'

How can I make the template infers the type of the return value and the arguments?

Comment: do you actually need to know the signature of the `std::function` ? Why not `template <typename F> auto async(F f) { ... }` ?  (this wont return a `std::function` though)

Comment: Your problem is that a lambda is not a std::function.  template deduction doesn't do any conversions.  looking for a dupe

Comment: You cannot infer the argument in the general case since it may not be unique. E.g. what happens, if you pass a `struct Foo{ void operator()(int){} void operator()(double){}};` ?

Comment: Note that something that can be done is returning a object providing a templated call operator that forwards the arguments to `std::async`: `template<class F>
struct FunctionCaller
{
    template<class...Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&...args)
    {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, m_f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    F m_f;
};

template <typename F>
auto asyncTest(F&& f) {
    return FunctionCaller{ std::forward<F>(f) };
}`